# Flutter on Android emmulator bottom control panel either disapears or overlaps my screen

Tags: flutter

I am working on a Flutter project, I've noticed that when I run it on an Android Emulator / Device, the bottom panel (with the controls on it, sorry I am not sure what this is called in Android) is sometimes either not showing or being shown on top of and hiding the bottom of the screen. Which is a problem as there is a Button located there.

Could someone please let me know how to control this in Flutter. What I want is that the Red button is always showing above the bottom panel.

Any help with this would be much appreciated

Please see the attached screen shots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the whole body widget inside Safe Area